# How would I retrieve a property's value by knowing another property's value in an object?

Tags: javascript, object

I would like to not use jQuery if possible. What I'm looking for:

```
var obj = [
  {
    name: "Sam",
    Job: "Developer"
  },
  {
    name: "Mike",
    Job: "Brother"
  } 
];

var testing = obj[name == sam].job // testing equals "Developer"
```

Comment: Why don't you make `obj` an object instead of an array, and use the `name` as the key?

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
var obj = [
 {
  name: "Sam",
  Job: "Developer"
 },
 {
  name: "Mike",
  Job: "Brother"
 } 
]    
var testing = obj
  .filter(function(person) { 
    return person.name == 'Sam'
  }).map(function(person) { 
    return person.Job
  })
```

console.log(testing)

or if you know that you're interested in the first one:

```
var obj = [
 {
  name: "Sam",
  Job: "Developer"
 },
 {
  name: "Mike",
  Job: "Brother"
 } 
]    
var testing = obj
  .filter(function(person) { 
    return person.name == 'Sam'
  })    var obj = [
 {
  name: "Sam",
  Job: "Developer"
 },
 {
  name: "Mike",
  Job: "Brother"
 } 
]    
var testing = obj
  .filter(function(person) { 
    return person.name == 'Sam'
  })
console.log(testing[0] && testing[0].Job)
```

and last but not least: If you know you have exactly one match, you can just do:

```
var testing = obj.filter(function(p) { return p.name == 'Sam'; })[0].Job
```

Answer (score 2):

So, you can't do it as simply as you have written, but you can filter and find what you're looking for. I've made it a generic function to make life easier for reusability:

```
function getArrObjPropertyValue(arr, searchProperty, searchCompare, returnProperty) {
  return arr.filter(function(item) {
    return item[searchProperty] === searchCompare;
  })[0][returnProperty];
}

console.log(getArrObjPropertyValue(obj, 'name', 'Sam', 'Job')); // Developer
```

Answer (score 1):

Make the comparison for the object's key separately from assigning the value like this:

```
var people = [
  {
    name: "Sam",
    Job: "Developer"
  },
  {
    name: "Mike",
    Job: "Brother"
  } 
];

var testing = null;
for (var person in people) {
  if (people[person].name === 'Sam') { testing = people[person].job; }
}
```